# how to resolve 'HttpHeaders' has private access in 'org.apache.http.HttpHeaders' error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, header, http-headers

I am trying to make an Http Request using RestTemplate, and it keeps on giving me the error: **'HttpHeaders' has private access in 'org.apache.http.HttpHeaders'**

I am simply trying to write this line:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

Comment: How did you intend to use this object in your code ? Note that `org.apache.http.HttpHeaders` is nothing more than a set of constants.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package name is wrong, in order to add headers when using Spring restTemplate, you should use `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.HttpHeaders` instead of `org.apache.http.HttpHeaders`. 
The following is the code snippet that adds request headers.

```
// request resource
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("headerName", "headerValue");

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://example.com", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor in `org.apache.http.HttpHeaders` is a private constructor - see source code clone {[here](https://github.com/Jean-Emile/org.apache.httpclient/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.java#L38)}. Since you are trying to invoke a private attribute, that error message is expected.

Attaching relevant code snippet for posterity:

```
public final class HttpHeaders {

    private HttpHeaders() {
    }

    // ....
    // bunch of defined constants
    // ....
}
```

The rationale behind this class is specified in the class docstring,

```
/**
 * Constants enumerating the HTTP headers. All headers defined in RFC1945 (HTTP/1.0), RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1), and RFC2518
 * (WebDAV) are listed.
 *
 * @since 4.1
 */
```

which is not the what you are trying to achieve here. If you wish to make a remote request, using apache library, with a request that contains headers, please follow {[this example](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-custom-http-header)}. Adding relevant code snippet for posterity:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SAMPLE_URL);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
client.execute(request);
```

If you are using >=4.3 of HttpClient, you would want to do something like this:

```
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
  .setUri(SAMPLE_URL)
  .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
  .build();
```

Comment: Please refrain from linking to external resources which are not official documentation. The links may disappear rendering the answer worthless. Better either find a StackOverflow answer that provides similar information or provide a short example in the answer.

Comment: Ah, excellent point @RealSkeptic. That definitely has bit me in the past. Let me update :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove compilation errors with

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

make sure you haven't imported `HttpHeaders` from apache http clients.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
```

this will not work as `HttpHeaders` has a private constructor.

Your import statement should be this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
```

And then you can add headers using the `add(String headerName, String headerValue)` method.

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994418/5771148)