# adding HttpHeaders in RestTemplate in SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to add a HttpHeaders in RestTemplate with SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

But I got a compilation error:

```
The constructor HttpHeaders() is not 
 visible
```

Comment: Does this help?
[Possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462128/basic-authentication-with-resttemplate-compilation-error-the-constructor-htt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove compilation error with `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();` make sure you haven't import `HttpHeaders` from apache http clients.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
```

this will not work as `HttpHeaders` has private constructor.

Your import statement should be this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
```

And then you can add headers using the `add(String headerName, String headerValue)` method.

Comment: For me it auto imported `java.net.http.HttpHeaders`, changing to `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` worked